# Oracle 11g backward compatiblity with 9.2.0.2

Tags: oracle11g, oracle9i

Currently `oracle 9.2i` database was migrated to `oracle 11.2g`, we din't face any issue in migration, but is it possible to make `oracle 11.2.` to behave backward compatible  to `oracle  9.2` by modifying `system` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to set the `COMPATIBLE` parameter to `9.2.0.`.  That wouldn't make Oracle 11g act completely like 9i, but it would come as close as possible.

Comment: I believe that COMPATIBLE only refers to the bit-level format of files on disk, not to any client-related behavior (e.g. dictionary tables). I also believe that you cannot simply decrease COMPATIBLE without a risk of data corruption. Am I wrong?